# dovecot login issue with plain passwords

Tags: dovecot

I am having an odd problem in dovecot, the first time I try to login via telnet dovecot gives a error, the second time it works, both within the same telnet session.

This is the telnet session, note the 'BAD Error in IMAP command received by server' and the "a OK" just after that :

```
telnet 192.168.1.2 143
* OK Waiting for authentication process to respond..
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE STARTTLS AUTH=PLAIN] Dovecot ready.
a login someUserLogin supersecretpassword
* BAD Error in IMAP command received by server.
a login someUserLogin supersecretpassword
a OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE SORT SORT=DISPLAY THREAD=REFERENCES THREAD=REFS MULTIAPPEND UNSELECT CHILDREN NAMESPACE UIDPLUS LIST-EXTENDED I18NLEVEL=1 CONDSTORE QRESYNC ESEARCH ESORT SEARCHRES WITHIN CONTEXT=SEARCH LIST-STATUS] Logged in
```

dovecot configuration

```
>dovecot -n
# 2.0.19: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 3.5.0-34-generic x86_64 Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
auth_debug = yes
auth_verbose = yes
disable_plaintext_auth = no
login_trusted_networks = 192.168.1.0/16
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
protocols = " imap"
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
```

This is the log file:

```
Jul  3 12:27:51 linuxServer dovecot: auth: Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/auth
Jul  3 12:27:51 linuxServer dovecot: auth: Debug: auth client connected (pid=23499)
Jul  3 12:28:06 linuxServer dovecot: auth: Debug: client in: AUTH#0111#011PLAIN#011service=imap#011secured#011no-penalty#011lip=192.168.1.2#011rip=192.169.1.3#011lport=143#011rport=50438#011resp=<hidden>
Jul  3 12:28:06 linuxServer dovecot: auth-worker: Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/auth
Jul  3 12:28:06 linuxServer dovecot: auth-worker: Debug: pam(someUserLogin,192.169.1.3): lookup service=dovecot
Jul  3 12:28:06 linuxServer dovecot: auth-worker: Debug: pam(someUserLogin,192.169.1.3): #1/1 style=1 msg=Password:
Jul  3 12:28:06 linuxServer dovecot: auth: Debug: client out: OK#0111#011user=someUserLogin
Jul  3 12:28:06 linuxServer dovecot: auth: Debug: master in: REQUEST#0111823473665#01123499#0111#0113a58da53e091957d3cd306ac4114f0b9
Jul  3 12:28:06 linuxServer dovecot: auth: Debug: passwd(someUserLogin,192.169.1.3): lookup
Jul  3 12:28:06 linuxServer dovecot: auth: Debug: master out: USER#0111823473665#011someUserLogin#011system_groups_user=someUserLogin#011uid=1000#011gid=1000#011home=/home/someUserLogin
Jul  3 12:28:06 linuxServer dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<someUserLogin>, method=PLAIN, rip=192.169.1.3, lip=192.168.1.2, mpid=23503, secured
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. In my case it appears to be a symbol in the password that caused this issue. I changed the password and I now it works.